# How do you escape and parse an xml file in python?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x

I'm finding resources to do either importing xml from a file or escaping html in python (so that the stuff like & ampersands are imported/converted properly and don't cause errors) but what I'm finding is not recent and/or doesn't really use methods that put both tasks together at the same time.

The task is to take an xml file generated from the amazon api, which always has unescaped ampersands in the output (I have to create a file because amazon has to approve the code before they allow me to make api requests from the program itself) and then parse through it, eventually providing me with an object I can get data from.

How would you do this in 2017? Easy answers definitely appreciated, I'm not exactly a pro at python coding yet.

Comment: there's an XML module in python, i.e. `import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET`

Comment: But it'll bug out due to the escaping that's necessary.